# ASP.NET MVC : Attends / Likes Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Event with info about it on a Display Event View. On that view, I am trying to to make Attend functuality, similar to Liking, but I have little problems. My logic is very simple and I would like to keep it so:  on click, it will increase int Attends by 1, but ...

First-I am getting inside the if(events==null)... And second is there a way to make it clickable once per User?

Here is my code:

Model:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    ...
    public int Attends { get; set; }
```

Event Create Action:

```
    //POST: Event/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          using (var database = new EventSpotDbContext())
            {
              var events = new Event(model.EventName,...);
                ...
                events.Attends = 0;
                database.Events.Add(events);
                database.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Main");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Event Attend Action:

```
 public ActionResult Attend(int? id)
    {
        using (var database = new EventSpotDbContext())
        {
            var events = database.Events.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
            if (events == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            events.Attends += 1;
            database.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
```

Event Details Action:

```
    //GET: Event/Details
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
         using (var database = new EventSpotDbContext())
        {
           var events = ...   .First();
           return View(events);
        }
    }
```

Details View

```
            @model EventSpot.Models.Event
            ...
            @Html.ActionLink("Attend Event", "Attend", "EventController", new {@id=Model.Id} )
            @Model.Attends
```

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear from you statement

Comment: I am getting inside the if(events==null) exception - HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request

Comment: Have you debugged it? Does the UI(View) really passes the id and your db works?

Comment: The value of `id` in your `Attend()` method is `null` You link is not correct and you not adding a route value (your adding a html attribute) - `@Html.ActionLink("Attend Event", "Attend", "Event", new { id=Model.Id }, null)`

Comment: Fixed it. Is there a way to make it clickable once per User?

Comment: @ivanov.g94 What do you mean _clickable once per User_?

Comment: If you'd want a user to be limited in only being able to click Attend once per event you'd be better off in adding a public List<Attendee> Attendees to store the userId's attending in there. You'll still be able to do a Count to easily return the amount of attendees as you're tracking now.

Comment: @ivanov.g94 did u solve it ?! and can you check the answer so help others ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Attend Event", "Attend", "EventController", new {@id=Model.Id}, null )
```

the isse that he was dealing with `{@id=Model.Id}` as html attributes not route attributes